# Using Loris image server for IIIF functionality, no responses

Tags: centos6, images

I've been trying to implement a small, local [IIIF](http://iiif.io/) supported image server using the [Loris](https://github.com/loris-imageserver/loris) image server. I'm running this on a Centos box (which did required some special setup [wizardry](https://github.com/loris-imageserver/loris/blob/development/doc/redhat-install.md).)

I was able to make it through the setup up process, and when hitting the loris server (for me, it's located at myserver/loris), I'm greeted with the freindly loris welcome screen:

> This is Loris, an image server that implements the IIIF Image API
>   Level 2. See http://iiif.io/api/image/2.0/ for details and
>   https://github.com/loris-imageserver/loris for the source code and
>   implementation details.

So far, so good.

That is until I try to move on to the IIIF's next step of publishing my metadata. I have no idea how to do this, and documentation on it is [fairly sparse](http://iiif.io/technical-details.html). I've tried placing my metadata in diffrent locations on my server where I would think the loris server would be looking (such as /usr/local/share/images (from the conf file), /var/www/loris2 (actual directory containing loris), /var/www/loris (web directory), etc). I keep just getting the error:

> Not Found: could not resolve identifier: [Identifier]  (404)

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why it can't resolve the identifier. I assume it's because I haven't placed the metadata in the right spot or in the correct way, but neither loris or IIIF seem to say where and how I'm supposed to do that. If anyone has any experience with this, any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So I was making this far more complicated in my head than it actually is.

The manifests are for the image viewers (like open [seadragon](http://openseadragon.github.io/), or [miradore](https://github.com/DMSTech/mirador)). The image server only needs an image to function, and it turns out I was just placing the image in the wrong spot. The location is stored in the loris2.conf file, and defaults to /usr/local/share/images. Placing images in here will cause loris to respond properly.